# groovy: remove numbers and period sign from list

Tags: groovy, katalon-studio

I have a following list:

```
def myOptions = ['1.0 Small', '2.0 Medium', '3.0 Large']
```

I want to remove numbers and period sign and just return the list as
`['Small', 'Medium', 'Large']`

I am trying the following but it still prints the original elements of list.

```
for (String el: myOptions) {
            StringUtils.remove(el, ".").replaceAll("[0-9]", "").trim();
            KeywordUtil.logInfo(el);
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thousands ways:

```
def myOptions = ['1.0 Small', '2.0 Medium', '3.0 Large']

def resultSplit = myOptions*.split( ' ' )*.getAt( 1 )
def resultReplace = myOptions*.replaceFirst( /\d+\.\d+ (\w+)/, '$1' )

assert resultSplit == ['Small', 'Medium', 'Large']
assert resultReplace == ['Small', 'Medium', 'Large']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `collect` to process the list, `split` each element on blank and take the *last* part of the split

```
def myOptions = ['1.0 Small', '2.0 Medium', '3.0 Large']

assert myOptions.collect { it.split(' ')[-1]} == ['Small', 'Medium', 'Large']
```

Answer (score -1):

It depends on some details of your requirements.  If you want to eliminate everything up to and including the last space character, you could do this.

```
def myOptions = ['1.0 Small', '2.0 Medium', '3.0 Large']

def results = myOptions.collect { value ->
   int idx = value.lastIndexOf(' ')
   if(idx >= 0) {
       return value[(1 +idx)..-1]
   }
   value      
}

println results
```

If the last space character isn't the thing to split on, you could use a similar approach but look for something other than the last space (like maybe eliminate everything up to and including the first space, for example).

Comment: FYI... `value[(1 +idx)..-1]` is roughly `value.substring(idx+1)`.